# sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated 's' command

Tags: sed

As for the instruction:

```
sed -i 's|/group/dairy/phuongho/garuns/out|$XXX/out/' exp/garuns.vpz
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this? Since I received the error indicated in the title of the question.

Comment: It's expecting to see a third `|` somewhere, but what are you expecting the command to do?

Answer (score 5):

Like the error message says, you're missing the final `|` to terminate the `s` command:

```
sed -i 's|/group/dairy/phuongho/garuns/out|$XXX/out/|' exp/garuns.vpz
                                                    ^
```

Note that since you're using single quotes, `$XXX` will be substituted into the file literally. If you want the value of the *variable* `XXX`, use double quotes (`sed -i "..."`) instead.

Also, you have a leading slash but no trailing slash in the pattern, and vice versa in the replacement. (This may be what you want as well, but it seems odd.)